# Electron + React + CSS loader without webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I am building a desktop application using electron js and react js. But when I run my electron app, it does not recognize external CSS files. I am using babel for compiling react code. 
Is there any way to use CSS loaders without using webpack?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be in addressing, so using internal css helps to fix it. Hope to be useful.

Comment: Did you mean, Using inline CSS? I want to avoid that so that I can have different CSS files at one place.

Comment: But, it's most simple way. I couldn't find any other solution, while had same problem.

Comment: yes right, using webpack we can tackle that. But I do not want to use webpack here. Please comment if you come across any solution.